# Single post Sidebar (based on category)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not good with PHP.

I use BeTheme and it's possible to display a sidebar for each category page.

Now i need to display a sidebar for single post based on category.

For exemple :

1. On the Category page called "WP1" I find the Sidebar "Sidebar WP1"
2. When i vist any single post on the Category "WP1" I need to display "Sidebar WP1"

This is the sidebar-blog.php file :

http://codepad.org/TPObjKqi

I need to edit the follinwg file to get the nedded result :

http://codepad.org/sppfGQRN

Any help please ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Widget Visibility from Jetpack can probably help you : http://www.wpsuperstars.net/category-specific-widgets/